# Showing ''Pages'' column for all subfolder in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows, pdf, windows-explorer

I have a folder that include many subfolders that contain PDF files. How can I config Windows Explorer that show Pages column (or any other column) for all subfolders?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right-click a column title, click `More...`, select `Pages` and click `OK`. Then click `Organize > Folder and search options`. In the `View` tab click `Apply to folders` and confirm.

Comment: Oh, Thanks, I thought this option only applies the listing mode to subforders! –

Comment: Never noticed the organize button until today! :)